# How can I configure Dreamweaver CS5 so that files with extension .less are edited with zen-coding?

Tags: dreamweaver, less, emmet

How can I configure DW so that files with extension .less are edited with zen-coding?

I can use within the zencoding notepad + + on windows normally. But now I want to use the same way inside DW.

Answer (score 2):

Edit (Dreamweaver on Mac) -> Preferences, File Types/Editors

Click the plus (+) button on the left-hand list. Enter ".less"  without quotes. With the .less entry selected, click the plus (+) button on the right-hand list, browse to and select the application that you want to open .less files with. Then click OK to apply the changes. Then double click a .less file in the files panel and it will open up with the specified application.

Re-reading the question, I can see that maybe it is ambiguously asking how to add .less files as an editable file type so that Dreamweaver can edit the file. If so, then follow the steps in this Adobe technote:
http://kb2.adobe.com/cps/164/tn_16410.html

Comment: Thanks Danilo, but still can not resolve here. I still can not expand using shortcuts zen coding ...

Comment: By your response it seems like (although you do not specify) that you are trying to edit the page within Dreamweaver *and* you are using a *third-party* extension to add Zen Coding editing ( http://code.google.com/p/zen-coding/ ) to Dreamweaver (as in not built into Dreamweaver). Is that correct, or are you trying to have Dreamweaver open .less files in another editor?

Comment: It seems that the method that the Zen Coding extension uses to identify CSS files relies on an internal Dreamweaver API call that for .css files identifies the file as CSS, but for added files, such as .less, it does not correctly identify the file as CSS. I've logged a bug with the Zen Coding project proposing an alternative method of file type identification, hopefully they can fix the issue in their next release: http://code.google.com/p/zen-coding/issues/detail?id=297

Answer (score 0):

You will need to search for the configuration configuration folder of the version of your dreamweaver. For example: if you are using version CS6, "c:\users[computer name]\appdata\roaming\adobe\dreamweaver cs6\en-us\configuration\menus\menus.xml"

You will now need to open the menu.xml file using either notepad or wordpad or any text editor then search for zencoding

change

to

Save the file and restart your dreamweaver.

try div#name and it should give you

I hope this works for you.